# Dropping columns and rows of huge matrix

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a huge matrix and would like to drop every other 4th row and every other 4th column in one shot. What is the element way to do that.

Regards,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`Drop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Drop):

```
Drop[Array[a, {9, 9}], {4, -1, 4}, {4, -1, 4}] //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccc}
>  a(1,1) & a(1,2) & a(1,3) & a(1,5) & a(1,6) & a(1,7) & a(1,9) \\
>  a(2,1) & a(2,2) & a(2,3) & a(2,5) & a(2,6) & a(2,7) & a(2,9) \\
>  a(3,1) & a(3,2) & a(3,3) & a(3,5) & a(3,6) & a(3,7) & a(3,9) \\
>  a(5,1) & a(5,2) & a(5,3) & a(5,5) & a(5,6) & a(5,7) & a(5,9) \\
>  a(6,1) & a(6,2) & a(6,3) & a(6,5) & a(6,6) & a(6,7) & a(6,9) \\
>  a(7,1) & a(7,2) & a(7,3) & a(7,5) & a(7,6) & a(7,7) & a(7,9) \\
>  a(9,1) & a(9,2) & a(9,3) & a(9,5) & a(9,6) & a(9,7) & a(9,9) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: Many thanks for your prompt answer.